# How can I prove the existence of the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ in ZFC Set Theory?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, set-theory, alternative-proof

How can I prove the existence of the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ in ZFC Set Theory?

We have the following axioms and theorems:

1. $\forall X\exists! Y\forall x(x\in Y\iff x\in X\land \phi(x))$
   Theorem from the **Axiom Schema of Specification**, from which the functional predicate "set builder notation" $\{x\in X|\phi(x)\}$ is introduced.
2. $\exists X(\emptyset\in X\land\forall x\in X(x\cup\{x\}\in X))$
   **Axiom of Infinity**

$\mathbb{N}$ is defined here (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Natural_Numbers) as the minimally inductive set, which is defined as:

$\mathbb{N}=\omega=\bigcap\{X\in\mathcal{P}(I)|\emptyset\in X\land\forall x\in X(x\cup\{x\}\in X)\}$ where $I$ is any inductive set.

The problem is $\{X\in\mathcal{P}(I)|\emptyset\in X\land\forall x\in X(x\cup\{x\}\in X)\}$ cannot be proven to exist because $I$ cannot appear at the conclusion of any proof by the restriction on existential instantiation.

The restrictions of existential instantiation are:

1. the constant must be new to the proof
2. the constant cannot be in the conclusion of the proof
3. the constant must replace all instances of the bound variable

See here:

1. $\exists X(\emptyset\in X\land\forall x\in X(x\cup\{x\}\in X))$
   **axiom of infinity**
2. $\emptyset\in I\land\forall x\in I(x\cup\{x\}\in I)$
   **existential instantiation $I$/$X$ 1**
3. $\forall X\exists! Y\forall x(x\in Y\iff x\in X\land \phi(x))$
   **theorem 1**
4. $\forall X\exists! Y\forall x(x\in Y\iff x\in X\land \emptyset\in X\land\forall x\in X(x\cup\{x\}\in X))$
   **schema elimination $\emptyset\in X\land\forall x\in X(x\cup\{x\}\in X)$/$\phi(x)$**
5. $\exists! Y\forall x(x\in Y\iff x\in \mathcal{P}(I)\land \phi(x))$
   **universal instantiation $\mathcal{P}(I)$/$X$ 4**

From here I would be able to assign $Y$ a constant symbol ($\mathbb{N}$,$\omega$,$\aleph_0$, etc.),

but I cannot include the constant $I$ in the conclusion of my proof. Therefore I cannot conclude that such a $Y$ exists.

How can I prove the existence of the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You have to show that the resulting $\omega$ is the same regardless of which inductive set $I$ you start the construction from.  Otherwise $\omega$ would be a function of $I$, and as you say you'd not be able to eliminate $I$.  I don't know how to formalize this though.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I am starting to wonder if \mathbb{N} can be proven to be a set at all or if I would have to settle for a class (not so ZFC).

Comment: Do you have a source for the restriction on I? Im not aware of any such restriction.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation#:~:text=In%20predicate%20logic%2C%20existential%20instantiation,a%20new%20constant%20symbol%20c.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch

Let $\phi(x)$ be any formula in which $x$ appears free, and neither $y, z$ nor $t$ appear free.  Prove the theorem schema

$$\exists x \phi(x) \implies \exists ! y \forall z (z\in y \iff \forall t( \phi(t)\implies z\in t)) $$

Now apply this to
$$\phi(x) := \text{Inductive}(x) := \emptyset\in x \land \forall p (p\in x \implies p\cup\{p\}\in x)$$

So letting
$$\text{Omega}(u) := \forall z (z\in u \iff \forall t (\text{Inductive}(t)\implies z\in t))$$

You get
$$\exists x \text{Inductive}(x) \implies \exists !y \text{Omega}(y)$$

You know
$$\exists x \text{Inductive}(x)$$
is true by the axiom infinity.  So you can deduce that
$$\exists !y \text{Omega}(y)$$
and this set is defined to be the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't $\text{Omega}(y)$ imply that every element in every inductive set is in $\mathbb{N}$ because it is a biconditional?

Comment: @IsaacSechslingloff:  Yes, $\mathbb{N}$, is the intersection of all inductive sets.   That is the definition.  If you start from any inductive set $I$, and take the intersection of all inductive subsets of $I$ you get the same thing.  Why?  Because the intersection of two inductive sets is inductive.  So if $x$ is in every inductive set - then $x$ is in every inductive subset of $I$.  If $x$ is in every inductive subset of $I$ - Then $x$ in every inductive set because if $J$ is any inductive set, $I\cap J$ is an inductive subset of $I$ so $x\in I\cap J\subseteq J$.

Comment: @IsaacSechslingloff: Moreover, you can prove from the definition that $\mathbb{N}$ is an inductive set, and that $\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of any inductive set.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a constructive approach.

Definition 1

Successor of a set x is $ 
x\cup\{x\} $

S(x) := $ x\cup\{x\} $

Definition 2

A set x is a successor if ∃y$\in$x($ x = y\cup\{y\} $)

Succ(x) ↔ ∃y$\in$x($ x = y\cup\{y\} $)

That's all we need alongside the ZF axioms to construct the Natural Numbers.

By the Infinity Axiom, there exists an Inductive set.

Let I be an inductive set

Let

$\omega$ = {x$\in$I | x = ∅ ∨ ( Succ(x) ∧ ∀y$\in$x(y = ∅ ∨ Succ(y))}

$\omega$ exists by the axiom schema of specification

I leave to you to show that it is the smallest inductive set.

First show that it is inductive.

Then Let X be an inductive set. For the purpose of contradiction assume X is a proper subset of $\omega$

Note: $\omega$ is not dependent on a particular inductive set I, since it is the smallest inductive set. If choosing a different inductive set I' , resulted in an inductive set ω', as both ω' and $\omega$ are the smallest inductive set. They must be equal.